# python simple compression text to text

Tags: python-3.x

Input string = "wwwwwwwwwkkktttttrrrrwww"
expected output = "9w3k5t4r3w"

I just want to know if there a more efficient/better way to achieve this please?

```
def my_encode(str1):
    temp = str1[0]
    cnt = 0
    final = ''
    for letter in str1:
        if letter == temp:
            cnt += 1
        else:
            final = final + str(cnt) + temp
            cnt = 1
            temp = letter
    final = final + str(cnt) + temp
    return final


print(my_encode('wwwwwwwwwkkktttttrrrrwww'))
```

Comment: That looks reasonably straightforward, and understandable; I wouldn't bother changing it unless you've actually measured it to be a bottleneck in your program.  One option if you did need to speed it up: use a regular expression to directly split your string into runs of the same character.  `re.sub(r"(.)\1*", lambda m: str(len(m.group(0))) + m.group(1), 'wwwwwwwwwkkktttttrrrrwww')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `itertools.groupby` will work for you

```
key = 'wwwwwwwwwkkktttttrrrrwww'
from itertools import groupby
print(''.join('{}{}'.format(len(list(k)), g) for g, k in groupby(key)))
>>> 9w3k5t4r3w
```